# OnCallEvents are not working in socket for two peers in android

Tags: android, sockets

Hi in the below code I was implemented callevents for sockets but it is not working.when I am try to press end call button, it is giving me an null pointer exception.

Can any one help how to resolve my issue.

OnCallEvents.java:

```
public interface OnCallEvents {
    void onCallHangUp();

    void onCameraSwitch();

    void onCaptureFormatChange(int width, int height, int framerate);

    boolean onToggleMic();
}
```

VideocallFragment.java:

```
public class VideocallFragment extends Fragment implements OnCallEvents {
 public VideocallFragment() {

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_main, container, false);
        surfaceView=rootView.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        surfaceView2=rootView.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView2);
        button_call_disconnect=rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_call_disconnect);
button_call_disconnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onCallHangUp();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Call Disconnected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
 @Override
    public void onCallHangUp() {
        socket.disconnect();
    }
```

Comment: You are not initializing the socket. you need to initialize it

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I have initialized socket

Comment: private Socket socket;

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I have initialized socket still it is not working

Comment: `socket = new Socket();` inside the `onCreate` method

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine for socket it is asking me pass 3 arguments?

Comment: Still it is not working